# What is the best practice to store SSH keys in database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, ssh, private-key

I am building rest APIs for an application in node.js, where user needs to upload their server details like,
**HostName**
**UserName**
**PrivateKey**

Once the user uploads all the details I am retrieving permissions from the server and display them in table format.

I don't want the user to upload the same server details again and again, so how do I store the private key and other server details securely in MongoDB database.

What kind of encryption techniques should I use?
I want to achieve this in node.js.

Comment: You can use `bcrypt` module.

Comment: If you only want to compare the infos in order to avoid a re-upload of the dame data. Add all data together and hash them. Then you can compare the hashes. (you can use sha512 hashing algorithm)

Comment: is it safer approach to storing encrypted private key in the database(MongoDB)?

Comment: I don't only want it to be encrypted for comparison purpose, I will also need the original key in future to retrieve data from the server.